# Using JDBC with PySpark over SSL

Tags: ssl, jdbc, pyspark

I'm trying to connect to a postgres server over jdbc using ssl and I'm having difficulty figuring out how to connect. Right now I have:

```
    jdbcDF = spark.read \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:<URL>") \
        .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename") \
        .option("user", "postgress") \
        .option("password", "<Password>") \
        .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
        .option("useSSL", "true") \
        .option("ssl", "true") \
        .option("sslmode", "verify-ca") \
        .load()
```

I have the certificate, root, and key on my local machine and I am getting the error:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3419.load.
: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: connection requires a valid client certificate

Answer (score 0):

It seems that jdbc over pyspark needs certificates to be in a very specific format. They must be DER format (and the key must be in pk8 format). To get the key in DER format, on ubuntu you can run:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -in dev-client-key.pem -outform DER -out dev-client-key.pk8 -v1 PBE-MD5-DES
```

For the root and client certificate, use something like:

```
openssl x509 -in ssl-key.key -out ssl-cert.der -outform DER
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, can i please check with u, how do u connect this to spark driver thereafter?

Answer (score 0):

thanks thomasbjones2. your comment really helped me. this is how i got my pyspark to connect postgredb.

this is in google cloudsql with ssl enabled:

my client and server cert were in .pem format. after reading thomasbjons2 suggestion i changed my key file to pk8 and the connection worked.

```
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in private-key.pem | openssl sha256
```

here is full code (hope this helps someone)

```
# url 
jdbc_url = "jdbc:postgresql://privateip:5432/database"

# Connection properties
properties = {
    "user": user,
    "password": password,
    "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver",
    "sslmode": "require",
    "sslcert": pk8_client_cert_path,
    "sslkey": client_key_path,
    "sslrootcert": server_ca_path
}

# Read data from PostgreSQL into a DataFrame
df = spark.read \
    .jdbc(jdbc_url, "your_table_name", properties=properties)
```